# How to focus and highlight a sentence(Text Widget) in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Is there a way to auto focus and highlight a paragraph of text when a page opens

For instance, how Google Docs highlights and focus on paragraph a comment was linked to when comment is clicked.

I want to pass a sentence to a new page, and find where the passed sentence exists on the new page, scroll the sentence into view  and highlight the sentence

Answer (score 0):

Create a FocusNode, the Focus Node can be passed to the TextField and it will give focus to the specific TextField on a specific event, e.g a button click or in your case navigating to a new page

```
class MainWidget extends State<MainWidget> {
  FocusNode focusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    focusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    focusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
```

*Pass it to the text widget*

```
return TextField(
     focusNode: focusNode)
```

and then your navigation

```
 RaisedButton(
  onPressed: //some navigation code  
             //or () => focusNode.requestFocus()
)
```